# assignment operator and conditional statements

Tags: c++, dynamic, if-statement

I have hard time understanding the following code `buffer[i] = arr ? arr[i] : 0;`. 
Does this  mean that if `arr` contain any thing then its equal to `buffer[i]` and if it doesn't it equals to `0`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int arr[5]={11,22,33,44,55};
    int * buffer;
    buffer = new int [5];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        buffer[i] = arr ? arr[i] : 0;//true/falls
        cout<<buffer[i]<<",";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    int arr2[5]={};
    int * buffer2;
    buffer2 = new int [5];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        buffer2[i] = arr2 ? arr2[i] : 0;//true/falls
        cout<<buffer2[i]<<",";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems the code may have been ported from when `arr` was allocated dynamically. Now it's on the stack so `arr` can never be `NULL` and so the check is useless

Comment: The check would make sense if it was `int* arr = new int[5]`.

Comment: so if i add this int *p=arr; would it make sense

Comment: @Karish - No, it checks if `arr` is a null pointer, but it cannot be as it is an array with 5 members.